# No handlers found for logger __main__

Tags: python, logging, handlers

I set up logging throughout my python package using a *logconfig.ini* file.

```
[loggers]
keys=extracts,root

[formatters]
keys=simple,detailed

[handlers]
keys=file_handler

[formatter_simple]
format=%(module)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_detailed]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[handler_file_handler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=detailed
args=('/ebs/logs/foo.log', 'a', 100000000, 3)

[logger_extracts]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file_handler
propagate=1
qualname=extracts

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=
```

But whenever I run my application, I get the following warning message in prompt,

```
No handlers found for logger __main__
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you calling the logger? I mean after `import logging' how do you create a logger? Include code sample if possible. I do not think it has anything to do with the logconfig.

Comment: LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Answer (score 16):

You have to call logging.basicConfig() first:

[Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

> The call to basicConfig() should come before any calls to debug(),
>   info() etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration
>   facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent
>   calls are effectively no-ops.

Or all logging.info('Starting logger for...') which will call logging.basicConfig() automatically. So something like:

```
import logging
logging.info('Starting logger for...') # or call logging.basicConfig()
LOG = logging.getLogger(name)
```

The module author's reason for this behavior is [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/863016)

Comment: I call logging.config.fileConfig(logfile) in my __init__.py file

Comment: I don't want to call BasicConfig. I think it may have to do with my logconfig.ini file but i can't figure out where

Answer (score 2):

I found my error.
It turns out the the root logger is used for main.
I just need to attach a handler to the root logger as so,

```
[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=file_handler
```